# Postgresql docker volume failing at windows

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker in my Macbook that is working, with the following script:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dz01
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - "8000"
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pz01
    ports:
        - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

When I replicate it at windows 10 without Hyper-V, so I working with docker toolbox the postgres container is failing with the following log:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.
2018-07-25T16:05:53.723099340Z 
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2018-07-25T16:05:53.723133181Z 
Data page checksums are disabled.
2018-07-25T16:05:53.723144716Z 
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
2018-07-25 16:05:55.787 UTC [30] LOG:  could not link file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.30" to "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": Operation not permitted
2018-07-25 16:05:55.792 UTC [30] FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
running bootstrap script ..
```

To get this log I deleted the `/postgres-data` directory in my windows folder, because previously I got an error refering of users permissions, so I thought about delete folder, and Docker automatically will generate the folder.

I google the error that I get and I can not find any related, so I do not know why is happening it...

Any help?

Comment: Have you shared the windows drive with Docker? Like so https://imgur.com/a/tXb4qHu

Comment: I did not, where can I find this option? I have take a look on kinematic and did not fInd the option.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Docker in MAC M2 ARM.

Disabling "VirtioFS" fixed my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve it.

I restart the whole computer, delete the repo and start all again from `desktop`. As I have seen in the Docker docs, the folder must be in a public path, such as `C:/Users/YourUser`

After that, I do not have any problem.